# PHP : cookie parse error

Tags: php, parsing, cookies

I have a problem with a text on a cookie when the cookie exist, I get an error : "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting" on the 
`if $_COOKIE['style'] == 'styles2'`

```
<?php 
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['style']))
        echo "<option value='styles' selected>Style 1</option>
              <option value='styles2'>Style 2</option>";
    else{
        if $_COOKIE['style'] == 'styles2'
            echo "<option value='styles'>Style 1</option>
                  <option value='styles2' selected>Style 2</option>";
        else
            echo "<option value='styles' selected>Style 1</option>
                  <option value='styles2'>Style 2</option>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You missed parenthesis to wrap the `if` content.

Comment: Yes, I programm in several languages and I have not see my error, but I know I'm idiot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not repeat yourself.

```
<?php 
$style = '';
if (isset($_COOKIE['style'])) $style = $_COOKIE['style'];
?>
<option value='styles'>Style 1</option> 
<option value='styles2'<?php if ($style == 'styles2') { ?> selected<?php } ?>>Style 2</option>
```

Comment: Please, please, do not do that unless you check `$_COOKIE['style']` against a white-list. XSS waiting to happen.

Comment: Checked or unchecked does not matter. Or points for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

You need parenthesis around expression:

```
if ( $_COOKIE['style'] == 'styles2')
```